# RStudio control + up, control + down shortcut functionality is unexpected

Tags: r, ide, rstudio

Note: I posted this question the other day in community.rstudio.com, but wasn't able to get a good answer, so now I'm asking here...

Link: https://community.rstudio.com/t/control-up-control-down-shortcut-functionality-is-unexpected/79965

Hello,

What do the shortcuts ctrl+up and ctrl+down do besides scroll up and down in the editor? In my script, ctrl+up moves the cursor to the first function definition in the file if the cursor is currently below the function. Ctrl+down again moves the cursor to the first function definition in the file if the cursor is currently above the function. Once the cursor is at the function definition, ctrl+up or down scrolls up or down a line (which is what I expect from looking at the shortcut assignments).

I just want the scroll up and down functionality. Any help? Thanks.

specs:
Windows 10
RStudio 1.2.1335
R version 3.6.1

Comment: I use the shrtcts package (https://github.com/gadenbuie/shrtcts / https://www.garrickadenbuie.com/blog/shrtcts/) to set/configure keybindings in RStudio and it sounds like this could be a solution to your problem. Definitely worth a look

Comment: Interesting, looks useful. In this case however I would like the existing shortcuts in RStudio to act as described - unless I am misunderstanding the intent.

Comment: any news? i have the same problem and i see no solutions around

Comment: @oibaFox I have not been using RStudio much of late so nothing from my end.